# ActiveX on Google Chrome Browser

Tags: google-chrome, sharepoint, google-chrome-extension, activex, sharepoint-2013

I'm Trying to run an ActiveX supported features on my enterprise (sharepoint 2013, lync 2010 etc...) on google Chrome browser.

A Brief of the issues i'm facing related to activeX on Chrome:

- integrate lync 2010 server with sharepoint 2013.
- runing a local .exe program.
- opening fileshare document ("file://").

I'm well aware of the fact that google will stop supported NPAPI soon.
Unfortunately, I have no access to the internet (using intranet) so alternatives such as "IETab" and other "ActiveX extensions" are not an option because their configuration must be online.

is there a way to handle ActiveX on Chrome under these circumstances?

Guys,
Hope anyone knows any way to approach this issue I'm helpless...

Thanks.

Comment: Hello, your question is very broad. If you describe what exactly you want to achieve, what you've tried and where you're stuck, we would have a starting point to help you.

Comment: No Problem, I've edited my question